# ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle, triggers

when i insert the value that time i got re-validation error,i also try many searching but not find any exact solution. 
this is my trigger code

```
  create trigger dlt_department
    after delete or insert or update
     on department
     for each row
   begin
    insert into         dept(d_id,dname,manager)values(:old.d_id,:old.dname,:old.manager);
  end;
```

this is my insert query :

```
insert into department values(40,'storage','kelvein');
```

Comment: Do **NOT** create your own tables and triggers in the `SYSTEM` schema, **never**. Create a regular user and do you work there. Don't do all your work as `SYSTEM` or `SYS`

Comment: The trigger name in the title do not match the trigger name in the posted code. If you want us to help you need to frame a decent question. Like, make it consistent. Provide us with the compilation errors. Although the chances are SYSTEM doesn't have a table called DEPARTMENT and/or DEPT. Which is as it should be. Now all you need do is drop the trigger from SYSTEM and build it in the proper schema.